# How does this use of aggregate work in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have been reading a spark book and this example is from the book

```
input = List(1,2,3,4,5,6)
val result = input.aggregate((0, 0))(
(acc, value) => (acc._1 + value, acc._2 + 1),
(acc1, acc2) => (acc1._1 + acc2._1, acc1._2 + acc2._2))
val avg = result._1 / result._2.toDouble
```

I am trying to understand how this works and what is the _1 and _2 at each step

(0,0) is the seed value or initial value
This list gets split into sep rdd's
lets say rdd1 contains List(1,2)
loop through this list

(acc, value)
acc  = ??? during each iteration of the loop
value = ??? during each iteration of the loop

(acc, value) => (acc._1 + value, acc._2 + 1)
during the first iteration of List(1,2) what is the value of acc._1 and _2 and value

(acc1, acc2) => (acc1._1 + acc2._1, acc1._2 + acc2._2))
acc1 (for 1,2) is something like 3,2 and acc2 (for 3,4) is 7,2
and this function adds 3+7 and 2+2 = 10,4 and add this value to the next group

Dear kind hearted Helpers,

please do not use jargons used in scala, I already read it and did not understand it hence came for help.

For a List(1,2) what will be the value of acc._1 and acc._2 during the first iteration of the list and during that iteration what is the value of 'value' and during the second iteration what are their values?

Comment: Aside: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30828056/how-does-aggregate-work-in-scala is a closely related question.

Answer (score 0):

`aggregate` works by taking in two functions, one which combines values within a partition and one which combines partitions.

The first function (the one for a single partition) could be more clearly written as

```
((sum, count), value) => (sum + value, count + 1)
```

The second function (to combine partitions) could be written as

```
((partition1Sum, partition1Count), (partition2Sum, partition2Count)) =>
    (partition1Sum + partition2Sum, partition1Count + partition2Count)
```

*Note on tuple notation:*

In Scala `(a, b, c)._1 == a`, `(a, b, c)._2 == b` and so on. `_n` gives you the nth element of the tuple.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of the aggregation function takes an initial value which in this example is a Tuple `(0,0)`, then the next parameter is `seqop` which is a function `(B, A) => A`,  in your example it would `(Tuple, Int) => Tuple`

What is happening here is this function is applied on every parameter of the list one by one. The tuple actually holds on the left side the sum of the list and on the right side the amount of the list passed so far. The result of the aggregation function is `(21, 6)`.

A side note: The implementation of `TraversableOnce` in Scala doesn't really use the `combop` parameter which in this example is `(acc1, acc2) => (acc1._1 + acc2._1, acc1._2 + acc2._2))` So you can just ignore it in this case. If you are familiar with Scala the code that gets executed is:

```
input.foldLeft((0, 0))((acc, value) => (acc._1 + value, acc._2 + 1))
```